# Inheritance of a Virtual Function

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, virtual-functions, clang++

I have the following piece of code.

```
class A {
public: 
  virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
public:
  void bar() { /* Do something */ }
}

void B::A::foo() {
   bar();
   // Do something else
}
```

When I try to compile this... I get an error saying it could not find `bar()`. Is this not the right way to instantiate the purely virtual function?

```
use of undeclared identifier 'bar'
```

Comment: `A` has an injected-class-name (like a typedef) member `A`, that is, `A::A` may refer to `A` itself. This member is inherited in `B`. Therefore, `B::A` refers to `A`. And of course, in the scope of `void A::foo()`, there's no member `bar`.

Comment: you have to add void foo() to your class B declaration. And as one answer already mentioned B::A::foo() makes no sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`void B::A::foo()` doesn't make much sense. It looks like you mean to implement `foo()` in `B`, for which you need to declare it in `B`'s class declaration, and then implement it:

```
class B : public A {
public:
  void foo();
  void bar() { /* Do something */ }
};

void B::foo() {
   bar();
   // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Do I need to prototype it again? Wont that show up as two functions.... `foo()` and `A::foo()`

Comment: @subzero Yes, and no. `A::foo()` has been declared in `A`. `B::foo()` is declared in `B`, and it overrides the former.

Answer (score 5):

Your code will not compile for a few reasons:

```
class A 
{
public: 
  virtual void foo() = 0; // this defining a pure virtual function - making A an abstract class
}; // missing ; here

class B : public A 
{
public:
  void bar() { /* Do something */ }
  // you never implement foo, making B another abstract class
}; // again with the ;

void B::A::foo() // this line makes no sense
{
   bar();
   // Do something else
}
```

I believe what you are trying to do is the following

```
class A 
{
public: 
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
    virtual void foo() { bar(); } // override A::foo
    void bar() { /* Do something */ }
};
```

If you are going to override a function, you must declare it as overridden.  If you derive a class from an abstract base class and do not implement its functions, your derived class is also an abstract base class.  Before you can instantiate any class, all of its functions must be non-abstract.

Comment: This just enables inherited classes of class B to override foo() method additionally. Should be also correct but the other solutions solve the problem already without compiling erros. Pretty sure but corrections appriaciated.

Comment: @ChristianSchack I'm not sure what you are trying to say.  Can you explain what you mean more clearly?

Comment: In class A the definition virtual void foo() = 0; is purely virtual or in other words abstract. Means a sub class has to implement this method. The declaration virtual void foo() in class B enables a Class C : public class B to override this function additionally but must not because it is declared as just virtual. But is for the question not necessary --> to be continiued

Comment: @ChristianSchack the only difference w.r.t. your code is that `B::foo()` is implicitly inline here, and this code has the missing `;`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes you are right. There is really no problem. My solution implies a seperate Header and Implementation file. You where completely right many minutes before my answer. But that wasn't the question of the comment i think. +1 for your answer

Comment: @ChristianSchack I think you are under the misconception that if you don't have the `virtual` keyword in `B` that the function somehow stops being virtual.  That is not the case.  Once it is declared to be virtual in `A`, it continues to be throughout the class hierarchy.  You can see that in this [example](http://ideone.com/hCIQs4).  The `virtual` keyword is not necessary in `B`, but I typically add it to make sure that anyone looking at `B` knows it is being overridden from another class (in this case `A`).

Comment: @ZacHowland Ok this is a nice notion. Yes to be true i was not sure until now thx for your hint. And i think every method which is at least protected must be implicitily virtual to meet OOP concept.

Comment: @ChristianSchack I'm not sure what you mean by this:  "every method which is at least protected must be [implicitly] virtual to meet OOP concept."  If you mean that any function that is protected or private must be virtual, that is not correct.  If you mean that any function that is protected or public must be virtual, that is also not correct (for the same reasons).  You only make functions virtual that you want to be able to override (that is, they make sense to override).

Comment: @ZacHowland I just meant without to have a book right before me that any method which is declared as protected or public must me implicitely virtual in C++. And here is the problem i think. Because i am switching between different languages C++ / Java. If i am wrong pls correct me i am really appriciated in more knowledge and effictivnes and code qualitiy. I have to say i didn't knew that a non virtual declared method (protect/public) is not allowed to be overriden in subclasses. I think i have to write some test code.

Comment: @ChristianSchack No.  Functions are only virtual if they are declared as such.  in the OP's example, it is virtual because it was declared that way in `A` (making it virtual for all derived classes).  A function that is never declared as virtual is not implicitly virtual.  If you have a function `bar` in `A` that is non-virtual and you declare `bar` in `B`, you have hidden `A::bar` for instances of `B`.  Additionally, if you have a pointer to `B` casted to a pointer to `A`, calling `pA->bar()` will call `A::bar`, not `B::bar` because there is no entry in the vtable for the function `bar`.

Comment: @ZacHowland I think i never thought in C++ about that hidden aspect. And of course this as implication to polymorphy expectation i had until now. Thank you this is a really nice discussion and i could learn a lot.

Comment: @ChristianSchack Keep in mind (since you are coming from a Java background):  C++ is **not** an object oriented langauge.  It is a functional language that allows for objects.  Aspects of OOP that are forced on you in languages like Java are not forced on you in C++.  Bjarne wrote a [brief](http://www.stroustrup.com/oopsla.pdf) on it a while ago if you would like more information.

Comment: @ZacHowland I really appriciated our discussion. It again showed me that it is not that easy to switch between different languages. You can always here these phrases: if one can programm Java you can programm C# or C++. That might be right in genereal but if you look in detail it is completely wrong. And it shows that you need a lot of experience to be an expert in just one of these languages. Thank you. I wish you nice Christmas Days and maybe we'll meet again here for further discussion. I have a lot of questions about C++ aspects.